# callbacks: function vs. function.bind

Tags: javascript, callback

Is there a difference between supplying a callback method with and without `bind` when I don't want to modify arguments? For example, is

```
async(console.log)
```

and

```
async(console.log.bind(console))
```

technically equivalent or are there cases with different behaviour?

Comment: That depends if the function requires the use of 'this'. If not, you don't need to bind. If so, yes you need to bind.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use bind if you want to pass function that need proper context like console.log otherwise you can just pass a function.
Try to run log as this:

```
var log = console.log;
log('x');
```

You will get exception because log need to called with console as context.

Comment: "You will get exception because log need to called with console as context." That depends on the implementation.

Comment: Yeah but It seems to work for all cases of callbacks I've encountered so far: `function foo(cb) {cb('bar')}; foo(console.log)`, Why doesn't it rely on `this` in that case?